# how to make div slide from right to left

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

got a code here from someone....

what I like is to make the sliding div from right slide to left, i mean it hides the div to the right and slowly slides to the left for 300px width.

HTML

```
<a id="loginPanel">quote</a>
<div id="userNav">User Area</div>
```

CSS

```
#loginPanel {
    color: #000;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#userNav {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: none;
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

Jquery

```
// Open / Close Panel According to Cookie //    
if ($.cookie('panel') == 'open'){    
    $('#userNav').slideDown('fast');
} else {
    $('#userNav').slideUp('fast');
}

// Toggle Panel and Set Cookie //
$('#loginPanel').click(function(){        
    $('#userNav').slideToggle('fast', function(){
        if ($(this).is(':hidden')) {
            $.cookie('panel', 'closed');
        } else {
            $.cookie('panel', 'open');
        }
    });
});
```

Please need help on this one. just to make the div slide right to left

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7m7uK/195/

Comment: `195` You deserve my undying respect.

Comment: But, for someone who has dedicatedly worked on same fiddle, why are you not switching to jQuery 1.9.1?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/596608/1577396

Comment: Have a look at this link too http://stackoverflow.com/q/4229422/1577396

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use jQueryUI and additional effects *Slide*

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide

Example:

```
$('#userNav').hide("slide", {direction: "left" }, 1000);
$('#userNav').show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
```

You can't use .slideToggle() to slide from left to right or vice versa, from http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/:

> The .slideToggle() method animates the height of the matched elements.
>   This causes lower parts of the page to slide up or down, appearing to
>   reveal or conceal the items. If the element is initially displayed, it
>   will be hidden; if hidden, it will be shown.

You should try and change your code to implement this code, but I think it's maybe better if you try with [@s15199d](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15659017/1081079) answer, than you don't need to use jQueryUI

Ok, I created jsfiddle, you must include jQueryUI in order to work, you have different combinations of slide directions:

http://jsfiddle.net/7m7uK/197/

Ok, created another fiddle with cookies

http://jsfiddle.net/7m7uK/198/

Comment: thank you for your answer, works but how can I apply the cookies in there? :-(

Comment: sorry, its bacause i wanted to save its state when opened or closed.

Answer (score 7):

**Without depending on JQuery-UI**

You need to place the content `<div>` you mean to slide inside a wrapper `<div>`. You then set the right margin of the content div to its negative width. The trick with the wrapper `<div>` is to have its `x-overflow` set to hidden so that it hides the content `<div>`. You can then use jQuery's native `animate()` routine to set the right margin to 0 to make the content `<div>` appear with a horizontal sliding effect.

HTML:

```
<div id="slider-wrapper">
    <div id="slider-content">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#slider-wrapper {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
#slider-content {
    width:         300px;
    margin-right: -300px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#slider-button").click(function () {
    $("#slider-content").animate({ "margin-right": 0 }, "slow");
});
```

Here's a demo that uses a handle `<div>` to expand and collapse a div:
http://jsfiddle.net/gingi/KUCaL/

Answer (score 3):

SLIDE DIV FROM RIGHT TO LEFT AND LEFT TO RIGHT

```
<div class="nav ">
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
       </ul>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
/*nav*/
.nav{
    position: fixed;
    right:0;
    top: 70px;
    width: 250px;
    height: calc(100vh - 70px);
    background-color: #333;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;

}
.nav-view{
    transform: translateX(0);
}
```

JS:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('a#click-a').click(function(){
    $('.nav').toggleClass('nav-view');
  });
});
```

https://web.archive.org/web/20161127062041/http://www.themeswild.com/read/slide-navigation-left-to-right

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#DivName").animate({"left": "-=300px", "opacity":1}, "slow");
```

Comment: hello there, but im not good at this, could you update the fiddle with your working code, that would be very helpful for me, thanks

Answer (score -4):

Have you tried this ?

```
if ($.cookie('panel') == 'open'){    
    $('#userNav').slideLeft('fast');
} else {
    $('#userNav').slideRight('fast');
}
```

Comment: `slideLeft()` and `slideRight()` are not part of jQuery by default, see [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/sliding/)

Comment: I'm sorry I thought that it was possible... See this to find a solution : http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide