# Quick way to scroll sibbling divs when div is deleted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the link provided I want the bottom div to transition nicely to the top instead of just jumping to the spot when the first div is hidden. Is there any nice and quick way to do this with css or some kind of library (I checked `isotope` but it doesn't seem to do what I want.)

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ykF3g/)

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/ykF3g/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using jQuery already, use it's animations...

```
$("div:first-child").slideUp(2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

[how to make div slide from right to left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658858/how-to-make-div-slide-from-right-to-left)

This should do the trick. It involves the usage of JQuery, but that isn't very hard to use.

Also, instead of sliding to the left or right, you code it so it slides to the top.