# Jquery Slide function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've been a little confused as how I'm supposed to connect my jquery to my page, and I'm still still relatively new to learning javascript/jquery.  When I put the script in the head nothing happens when I click on the  I have set up in my file below.  But on my jfiddle it works fine.

I have a portion of my site where I want to have a mock iphone where people who visit the page can click on it.

I used this jfiddle I found on stack overflow:
[how to make div slide from right to left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658858/how-to-make-div-slide-from-right-to-left)

There's a link that goes to jqueryui and shows the script for the slide effect there.  Am I supposed to use this in the head?

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

This is my jfiddle that I tweaked slightly as to what I'm looking to achieve:
http://jsfiddle.net/tokyothekid/weujtht5/

Here's my current code in the head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<script>
$( document ).click(function() {
  $('#iphone-button1').click(function(){

                if ($('#iphone-panel2').is(':hidden')) {

                   $('#iphone-panel2').show('slide',{direction:'right'},1000);
                } else {

                   $('#iphone-panel2').hide('slide',{direction:'right'},1000);
                }
});
    </script>
```

Here is my html:

```
    <div id="iphone-panel1">
       logo 
       <a id="iphone-button1">start</a>
    </div>
<div id="iphone-panel2">User Area</div>
```

My CSS:

```
#iphone-panel1{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
   position:absolute;
}

a {
    color: #000;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
}
#iphone-panel2 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: none;
    background: red;
    position:relative;
}
```

Appreciate all the help

Comment: Works on `fiddle` not on my page etc are hard to answer as that will be machine specific issues.. Just try to paste complete `html` so that we can identify whether there are any issues in `html`

Comment: make sure that your src on the script tags are the correct path to the jQuery files. Seems like they aren't loading correctly.

Comment: Are you using tools like Firebug? It seems you just forget to close the function, add one more }); and you r good to go.. also use $( document ).ready instead of $( document ).click

Comment: @NyomanAdityaTripalguna  changing it to $(document).ready and adding the }); was it!