# Slide div to the right and left on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navigation bar that on mobile it has overflow and for people to see all the choices they need to scroll to the right or to the left. I want to add buttons with arrows so when people click for example on the right one the nabber will slide on its own to the right.

I have tried jQuery

```
$('#admin-menu').animate({width:'toggle'},350);
or
$(#admin-menu).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
or
$('#admin-menu').slideToggle( "slow" );
```

but none of this seems to work how I want, it makes the nabber dissappear.

the menu bar with slider

```
<nav id="admin-menu">
    <span class="tab active" id="locations-tab">
      <h6>Dashboard</h6>
    </span>
    <span class="tab" id="users-tab">
       <h6>Users</h6>
    </span>
    <span class="tab" id="users-tab">
       <h6>Users</h6>
    </span>
    <span class="tab" id="users-tab">
       <h6>Users</h6>
    </span>
    <span class="tab" id="users-tab">
       <h6>Users</h6>
    </span>
    <span class="tab" id="users-tab">
       <h6>Users</h6>
    </span>
</nav>

//The button to slide
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-right right-slider" onClick="slider()"></I>
```

The function

```
function slider(){
    console.log('Im here!!')

    $('#admin-menu').animate({width:'toggle'},50);
}
```

I want to be able to click the button and have the navigation-bar scroll to the left.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658858/how-to-make-div-slide-from-right-to-left

Comment: Can we see your CSS, too? I think a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might help demonstrate the issue.

Comment: It sounds like you might be looking to [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) [scrollLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft), but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @showdev scollLeft worked like a charm!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS translation to achieve this, activated upon a button click or something similar.

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
  $("#test").css("transform", "translateX(100px)");
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MRJzog

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! :)

Comment: Sure! Feel free to mark it as the answer to your question!

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help you.

```js
$(".left-slider").click(function(){
 $('#admin-menu').animate({width:'hide'},1000);
});

$(".right-slider").click(function(){
 $('#admin-menu').animate({width:'show'},1000);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="admin-menu">
    <span class="tab active" id="locations-tab">
      <h6>Dashboard</h6>
    </span>
    <span class="tab" id="users-tab">
       <h6>Users</h6>
    </span>
    <span class="tab" id="users-tab">
       <h6>Users</h6>
    </span>
    <span class="tab" id="users-tab">
       <h6>Users</h6>
    </span>
    <span class="tab" id="users-tab">
       <h6>Users</h6>
    </span>
    <span class="tab" id="users-tab">
       <h6>Users</h6>
    </span>
</nav>
<i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-left left-slider"></i>
<i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-right right-slider"></i>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! but this made my navbar disappear :( But with simply scrollLeft I achieved the wanted result! :)