# I want only slide right(horizontal) using jquery not toggled ul li elemnts

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, css

I am trying to do slide right but not working, When i am tryiing to write 'right' or 'left' instead of 'toggle'. it is not working. Please help me My code is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('ul').hide();

});
function next(){

$('ul').animate({width: 'toggle'}, 1000);
}
</script>
<style>
ul{height:30px; overflow: hidden; }
ul li{ display: inline-block; padding: 10px; }
</style>
</head>

<body><p onclick="next()">next</p>

<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working demo here: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pcgy3/25/)

JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul").hide();
    $("p").click(function(){        
           $("ul").show("slide",{direction: 'right'})
    });

});
```

Comment: Hello, web2008,

This is working, But can you please suggest from left to right, it slids right to left

Comment: Change the direction form right to left as shown below: $("ul").show("slide",{direction: 'left'})

Comment: I have been tested it in my localhost but not working on localhost, it is working well on fiddle, but not working on localhost. please suggest me.

Comment: Have you included JQUERY UI js file?

Comment: Tell me how to include it, i dont know

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script> These are latest Jquery and Jquery UI js files.include them in <head> section. If you have already included JQuery js file then no need to add it once again.

Comment: Hello still that problem, toggle is workin, but left, right , not working... :(

Comment: Yaa, i have been solved it, there was small mistake by me, its working , now, Thanks

Comment: If this answer is helpful to you in resolving the issue then accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Sliding solution provided at: [jQuery .slideRight effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229422/jquery-slideright-effect)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slider').click(function() {
        $(this).animate(
            {
                'margin-left':'1000px'
                // to move it towards the right and, probably, off-screen.
            },1000,
            function() {
                $(this).slideUp('fast');
                // once it's finished moving to the right, just 
                // removes the the element from the display, you could use
                // `remove()` instead, or whatever.
            }
        );
    });
});
```