# What is the best method for sliding in new content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to be able to create a similar effect that [Facebook paper link](https://www.facebook.com/paper)  have created.

Having a button on the right hand slide that slides in new content while then creating the back button. But I don't know what language or what method is best to implement this. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Really and truthfully if you have to ask, you should probably use a plug-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and dirty would be use jQuery and jQuery UI.

```
$('#your-object').show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
```

For a more detailed answer, see [jQuery .slideRight effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229422/jquery-slideright-effect)