# Open div from 0px left to right

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I'm trying to open a row of block with an animation.
The goal is to go from 2 block to 3 blocks by clicking a button.
The block that I want to add has to go in the middle and has to fade in from left to right.

I have two problems:

1. The blocks are not aligned on 1 single line. (The first block is lower)
2. When I click to open the middle block it opens from the bottom to the top (I want it to go from left to right)

   This is the code that I used the rest you can see in the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h3dgfe2w/1/)

   ```
   $('.openRed').on('click', function (e) {
   $('.redHide').toggleClass('redShow').toggleClass('redHide');
   ```

   Thank you, if it's not clear let me know!

Comment: You probably want to tackle this with jQuery's `.animate()` function rather than CSS transitions.

Comment: I did try that. Since i'm not that experienced in jQuery I couln't figure that out and I got stuck. So if you know how I would love to know so I can learn.

Comment: https://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596608/slide-right-to-left#answer-615225

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229422/jquery-slideright-effect

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823305/slide-div-left-right-using-jquery

Comment: @adeneo if you think is a duplicate mark it as duplicate. Don't fill the comment's table with links.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude - There's just so many, I couldn't decide which one to use

Comment: Ok, so choose the best and mark it

Comment: If you say so boss, I'll get right on it

Comment: @MarLen you might want to have a look at my answer, to see how it should be done with a good coding style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The blocks are not aligned on 1 single line. (The first block is lower)

The baseline of an `inline-block` element is the baseline of its [last line box in the normal flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19366401/css-inline-block-elements-not-lining-up-properly/19366432#19366432). In other words, the elements are being aligned based on the text in the button element. You could add `vertical-align: top` to that element in order to fix the alignment issues:

```
.blue {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

> When I click to open the middle block it opens from the bottom to the top (I want it to go from left to right)

Then transition the width rather than the height. Set the initial height to `100px`, and then specify that the transition should only transition the width of the element:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/xyd7h4dk/)

```
transition: 2s width ease-in;
```

Side note(s):

You don't need to use the `.toggleClass()` method twice. Just specify both classes.

```
$('.openRed').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.redHide').toggleClass('redShow redHide');
});
```

However, you really only need to toggle the `redShow` class:

```
$('.openRed').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.redHide').toggleClass('redShow');
});
```

You can also use the `transition` shorthands:

For instance:

```
transition: 2s width ease-in;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining. Right now the button doesn't toggle. It just opens en doesn't close is that whats supposed to happen?

Comment: @MarLen I fixed that issue in my answer, please feel free to ask

Comment: @MarLen Just toggle the `redShow` class rather than both: https://jsfiddle.net/bxg1jjuu/

Comment: Thank you, really helped me alot!

Answer (score 3):

I optimized the class and animation, in a way I think you intended to do it: 
please feel free to ask if you don't understand something, it's always good to learn new things ;)

```js
$('.openRed').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.red').toggleClass('show')
});
```

```css
.blue {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.red {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
}
.red.show {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  transition: 2s ease-in;
}
.yellow {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blue">
  <button class="openRed">
    Open Red
  </button>
</div>
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="yellow"></div>
```

Comment: It's better the solution of @JoshCrozier : http://stackoverflow.com/a/34746661/5035890

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude what?

Comment: Floats causes harm in the flow of the document, in this case floating the elements you'll obtain the elements outside the normal flow. With inline-block as @JoshCrozier said the problem solves and the flow still perfect.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I updated my answer, you can now remove you downvote -.- also I don't think that float:left is worth a downvote

Comment: Your new answer is better, but I think that in this case, float:left is meritory of downvote because you modify all the flow in the page of the OP. when OP try to integrate your solution with float maybe he will got more problems than now. I remove my downvote, and sorry if I disturb you.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you seaking: https://jsfiddle.net/h3dgfe2w/

```
body{
  display: inline-block;
}

.row{

}

.block {
  float:left;
  margin-left:5px;
}

.blue {
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}

.red {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100px;
    width: 0px;
    background-color: red;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.yellow {
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
}


@-webkit-keyframes slideInLeft {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes slideInLeft {
  from {
    width: 0px;
    visibility: visible;
  }

  to {
    width: 100px;
  }
}

.slideInLeft {
  -webkit-animation-name: slideInLeft;
  animation-name: slideInLeft;
  visibility: visible;
}


.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```